# PHP - resetting $_SESSION["SESSION_PASSWORD"] not working

Tags: php, session, variables, passwords

I'm trying to create a change password option on my site. I'm using session vars to keep track of the users username/password .. which I pass to an authcheck function on each page.

The problem I'm having is this. When I change the users password, no more pages will load because the password that's stored in the session var is not the same as whats in the DB anymore.

How do I go about changing the session var to reflect the new pass? Currently I'm trying:

`$_SESSION["SESSION_PASSWORD"] = $newPass;`

Which I assumed would reassign what was in `SESSION_PASSWORD` to the new pass. Doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: Connect to the DB and update the variable...

Comment: @ColeJohnson it doesn't work. I tried unsetting the session variable as well but it still won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How / Where in your code are you setting the session variable in the first place?

Perhaps start_session() has not been called yet?

Comment: Also note that it's a /really bad idea/ to store people's passwords in their sessions, but if you're only new to PHP I guess the experience may come in handy later, when you store something less important like a token or something.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. Gotta start somewhere :)